# CORS error in calling an API in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, cors

its my code:

```
<script>

function testingAPI(){
theUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/juliolimacostavalladares";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onload = function() {
  alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
};
xmlHttp.onerror = function() {
  alert(xmlHttp.status);
};
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false); 
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

</script>

<body>
  <button onclick="testingAPI()"> send request </button>
</body>
```

and when i run it i got CORS error.
what can i do to resolve the problem?
thank you.

when i try the url in a browser it works.
but in javascript it raises a CORS error.

Comment: Per https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#cross-origin-resource-sharing, you need to make sure your request includes an appropriate `Origin` header. Consider something like Axios or fetch instead of manually creating XMLHttpRequest objects.

Comment: @ceejayoz There's no need to make sure that the request contains an `Origin` header. Including (or not) such a header is the browser's responsibility, not the client's. You only need to manually include an `Origin` header if you're testing a resource's CORS configuration using some non-browser user agent like `curl`.

Comment: @jub0bs You're right; I ran OP's code in CodePen. `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");` causes their issue, it seems. Works fine with that line removed.